# Storing MySQL fetch_assoc() in variable

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

If I have something like 
    $data = getSomeData();

which is an associative array, and then I use things like `$data['username']` and `$data['id']` and so on, will it have to call `getSomeData();` every time I use something from the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, the results of `getSomeData()` are stored in `$data`, so you are using the values in `$data`.

Answer (score 0):

No. If `getSomeData();` returns an array, then `$data` is the value of the array. Why would it call the function?

There is something in PHP called magic methods, which applies to Classes. I'd have to double check, but it is something like `__get` that you can override. But I'm going to leave that alone, because this is already to complicated for this question.